# Improve FloatBuffers' Performance with Native C/C++

Tags: android, android-ndk, floatbuffer

I'm writing an OpenGL ES 2.0 Engine and using FloatBuffers, but I've heard FloatBuffers are slow on Android Froyo and moderatly quicker on Gingerbread.

So what I want to know is, whether it's possible to create and edit buffers with native C/C++(Android NDK).

Does it really improve the performance?

Which Headers have to be included?